# Object DOM Document should be created. Magento 2

Tags: magento2, admin, backend, admin-panel

I'm trying to login in Magento 2 **Admin Panel** when I try to login to **Admin Panel** firstly the login page comes perfectly like
[image]

but after when I **logged In** it gives me an **error**

> Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Object DOMDocument should be created.

you can also see the error in the image below 
[image]
now what is the problem n how can I solve this? Thanks

Comment: Share your code. I think something is missing in your XML.

Comment: which XML file?

Comment: As per your question screen-shoot. you have done customization in the admin login form. so it might be a chance something is missing or wrong.

Comment: this  exception came because of you have a mistake in .xml file

Comment: Share your log file error.